# Stop queue on error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, queue

I am trying to delete my queue on error.

I have tried the following:

file: `global.php`

```
Queue::failing(function($connection, $job, $data)
{
    // Delete the job
    $job->delete();
});
```

But when my queue fails like this one does:

```
public function fire($job, $data){
    undefined_function(); // this function is not defined and will trow a error
}
```

Then the job is not deleted for some reasons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their [user manual](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#basic-usage), section *Checking The Number Of Run Attempts*:

> If an exception occurs while the job is being processed, it will automatically be released back onto the queue.

I think you need to set the maximum number of tries to 1, so the job will fail on the first error.

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can prevent your job from throwing exception

```
public function handle()
{
  try {
    //your code here
  }catch (\Exception $e){
    return true;
  }


}
```